# How do you automatically assign a field in a Meteor simple schema to a variable as soon as its declared?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am making a simple schema in meteor with the Aldeed packages, and for the schema, I need to have it so one of the values is not influenced by user input, but is automatically assigned to variable. Here is an example of a schema:

```
LobbySchema = new SimpleSchema({
game: {
    type: String,
    label: "Game"
  },
  console: {
    type: String,
    label: "Console"
  },
  players: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Players"
  },
  mic: {
    type: Boolean,
    label: "Mic"
  },
  note: {
    type: String,
    label: "Note"
  },
  gamertag: {
    type: String,
    label: "Gamertag"
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Created At",
    autoValue: function(){
      return new Date()
    },
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden"
    }
  }
});
```

For the first value "game", I need to assign a variable to that.

Comment: Can't you just set it when you need it, like instantiate a variable before the user can add the other ones? I dont know if a way to allow simpleschema to set it.

Comment: how would I instantiate a variable before the user can add the other ones in the situation other than doing that, thats sorta of the purpose of the question. @selten98

Comment: Why not just `autoValue`?